# Application not showing in ArgoCD when applying yaml

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, devops, argocd, gitops

I am trying to setup ArgoCD for gitops. I used the ArgoCD helm chart to deploy it to my local Docker Desktop Kubernetes cluster. I am trying to use the app of apps pattern for ArgoCD.

The problem is that when I apply the yaml to create the root app, nothing happens.
Here is the yaml (created by the command `helm template apps/ -n argocd` from the my public repo `https://github.com/gajewa/gitops`):

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: root
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    server: http://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: argocd
  project: default
  source:
    path: apps/
    repoURL: https://github.com/gajewa/gitops.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
```

The resource is created but nothing in Argo UI actually happened. No application is visible. So I tried to create the app via the Web UI, even pasting the yaml in there. The application is created in the web ui and it seems to synchronise and see the repo with the yaml templates of prometheus and argo but it doesn't actually create the prometheus application in ArgoCD. And the prometheus part of the root app is forever progressing.

Here are some screenshots:
The main page with the root application (where also argo-cd and prometheus should be visible but aren't):
[image]
And then the root app view where something is created for each template but Argo seems that it can't create kubernetes deployments/pods etc from this:
[image]

I thought maybe the CRD definitions are not present in the k8s cluster but I checked and they're there:

```
λ kubectl get crd
NAME                       CREATED AT
applications.argoproj.io   2021-10-30T16:27:07Z
appprojects.argoproj.io    2021-10-30T16:27:07Z
```

I've ran out of things to check why the apps aren't actually deployed. I was going by this tutorial: https://www.arthurkoziel.com/setting-up-argocd-with-helm/

Comment: You should be able to click in the individual root/argocd/prometheus boxes and see the underlying applications. Have you tried that?

Comment: You said you apply the yaml to create the root app. How do you apply the yaml? Are you applying it in the right namespace? You can try to run `kubectl get apps -A` for all namespaces to see if you create it where needed.

Comment: I to have similar issue. And I do see  kubectl get apps -A that they are created in namespace argocd and with the correct names. But it does not find custom project name. I do not want to use 'default' project.

Answer (score 11):

the problem is you have to use the below code in your manifest file in **metadata**:

> just please change the namespace with the name your **argocd** was deployed in that namespace. (default is argocd)

```
metadata:
  namespace: argocd
```

Comment: This was it for me. I didn't realise that the namespace of the ArgoCD Application CRD has to be the same as the namespace to which ArgoCD is deployed, otherwise it doesn't pick up the application.

Answer (score 0):

From another SO post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70276193/13641680

> It turns out that at the moment ArgoCD can only recognize application declarations made in ArgoCD namespace,

Related [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/3474)

Comment: Is there any reason you duplicated the answer provided by @mehrdad.f 42 days before you?

Comment: It's not duplicated. It's an addition with more resources

Comment: You could have easily added those as comments on the first answer.